# sorting a tuple that contains string and numbers in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, tuples

I have a list like this;

```
List = [('apple 5', 12), ('apple 3', 2), ('apple 6', 10),('apple 4', 15), ('apple 9', 11), ('apple 7', 14), ('apple 18', 10), ('apple 16', 10),('orange 5', 4), ('orange 4', 7)]
```

I know how to sort the list normally.

```
for i in sorted(List):
  print(i)
```

this gives;

```
('apple 16', 10)
('apple 18', 10)
('apple 3', 2)
('apple 4', 15)
('apple 5', 12)
('apple 6', 10)
('apple 7', 14)
('apple 9', 11)
('orange 4', 7)
('orange 5', 4)
```

But can I sort something like this?

```
('apple 3', 2)
('apple 4', 15)
('apple 5', 12)
('apple 6', 10)
('apple 7', 14)
('apple 9', 11)
('apple 16', 10)
('apple 18', 10)
('orange 4', 7)
('orange 5', 4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use your own key to sort, and use multiples criterias, the syntax is `sorted(values, key = lambda x: (criteria_1, criteria_2))`

```
values = [('apple 5', 12), ('apple 3', 2), ('apple 6', 10), ('apple 4', 15),
          ('apple 9', 11), ('apple 7', 14), ('apple 18', 10), ('apple 16', 10),
          ('orange 5', 4), ('orange 4', 7)]

for i in sorted(values, key=lambda x: (x[0].split(" ")[0], int(x[0].split(" ")[1]))):
    print(i)
```

Or using a method to get a proper code

```
def splitter(v: str):
    s = v.split(" ")
    return s[0], int(s[1])

for i in sorted(values, key=lambda x: splitter(x[0])):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to assign your own `key`:

```
l1 = [('apple 5', 12), ('apple 3', 2), ('apple 6', 10),('apple 4', 15), ('apple 9', 11), ('apple 7', 14), ('apple 18', 10), ('apple 16', 10),('orange 5', 4), ('orange 4', 7)]

def sort_key(x):
    word, num = x[0].split()
    return word, int(num), x[1] # Sort by word, than the number as an integer, than the final number

l1.sort(key=sort_key)
print(*l1, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
('apple 3', 2)
('apple 4', 15)
('apple 5', 12)
('apple 7', 14)
('apple 9', 11)
('apple 16', 10)
('apple 18', 10)
('orange 4', 7)
('orange 5', 4)
```